# Cassandra UDT nested set InvalidTypeExeception

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, user-defined-types

I am experimenting with UDT's in Cassandra 2.1 and struggling with an InvalidTypeExeception.

I am setting the tables up as:

```
 session.execute("CREATE TYPE mykeyspace.address (" +
                    "  street text," +
                    "  city text," +
                    "  zip_code int," +
                    "  phones set<text>" +
                    ");"
    );
    session.execute("CREATE TYPE mykeyspace.fullname (" +
                    "  firstname text," +
                    "  lastname text" +
                    ");"
    );
    session.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.users (" +
                    "  id uuid PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "  name frozen <fullname>," +
                    "  direct_reports set<frozen <fullname>>," +
                    "  addresses map<text, frozen <address>>" +
                    ");  ");
```

And then running the following as a test:

```
PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO mykeyspace.users (id, name, addresses) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");

UserType fullNameType = session.getCluster().getMetadata().getKeyspace("mykeyspace").getUserType("fullname");
UserType addresType = session.getCluster().getMetadata().getKeyspace("mykeyspace").getUserType("address");

BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);

UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

UDTValue name = fullNameType.newValue().setString("firstname", "john").setString("lastname", "smith");


UDTValue address = addresType.newValue()
        .setString("street", "1 long st")
        .setString("city", "sydney")
        .setInt("zip_code", 2000)
        .setSet("phones",ImmutableSet.of("123", "456", "789")); // ERROR THROWN HERE

Map<String, UDTValue> addresses = new HashMap<String, UDTValue>();
addresses.put("home", address);
session.execute(boundStatement.bind(
        uuid,
        name,
        addresses
));
```

I am receiving the following error against the .setSet("phones"...) line:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: 
Column phones is of type 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FrozenType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SetType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type))', cannot set to a set
```

Just confused at what I am doing wrong and where I am missing something, I am sure its something obvious but can't figure it out...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also facing same error

Answer (score 1):

That would be a bug in the driver. Provided you've made sure that you're using the last released version of the driver (to make sure it hasn't been fixed yet), please report this on the [java driver jira](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA).

Comment: Tested on 2.1.4 & 2.1.3. I've opened a ticket [InvalidTypeExeception when setting a UDT collection](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-671)